# exchange 2003 repeating every email received for all users

Tags: exchange-2003

I have this problem, All users received deferent mails ,all this mails repeated . I have exchange 2003 with eXchange POP3, How can I stop this repeating Emails

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any antivirus software installed on the Exchange server? If so, is it scanning incoming emails or the Exchange directories? If so, try disabling it and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your activity 
but server still sending same messages